# Python regex chokes on \n

Tags: python, regex, search, line-breaks, proximity

I wish to use a regex in Python that reads text, finds all instances in which < emotion > markup exists within the same sentence as < location > markup, then allows those sentences to be print to a unique line of an output file:

```
import re
out = open('out.txt', 'w')

readfile = "<location> Oklahoma </location> where the wind comes <emotion> sweeping </emotion> down <location> the plain </location>. And the waving wheat. It can sure smell <emotion> sweet </emotion>." 

for match in re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)((?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\bemotion>(?=\s|\.|$))(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\blocation>(?=\s|\.|$)).*?\.(?=\s|$))', readfile, flags=re.I):
    line = ''.join(str(x) for x in match)
    out.write(line + '\n')

out.close()
```

The trouble is that if I read in a file that contains line breaks, the regex fails:

```
import re
out = open('out.txt', 'w')

readfile = "<location> Oklahoma </location> where the wind \n comes <emotion> sweeping </emotion> down <location> the plain </location>. And the waving wheat. It can sure smell <emotion> sweet </emotion>." 

for match in re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)((?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\bemotion>(?=\s|\.|$))(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\blocation>(?=\s|\.|$)).*?\.(?=\s|$))', readfile, flags=re.I):
    line = ''.join(str(x) for x in match)
    out.write(line + '\n')

out.close()
```

Is there any way to modify this regular expression so that it won't choke when it hits \n? I would be most grateful for any advice others can lend on this question.

Comment: Either read the file as lines, or strip out the newline character before applying the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add re [`re.S` or `re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) (they are the same thing) to the flags in your regex.  This will cause `.` to also match newlines.  So the new value for the `flags` argument would be `re.I | re.S`.

Comment: Thank you, F.J! I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.DOTALL` / `re.S`

```
flags = re.DOTALL | re.I
```